# TypeORM: update item and return it

Tags: typescript, rest, orm, api-design, typeorm

As far as I know, it's a best practice to return an item after it has been updated. TypeORM's `updateById` returns `void`, not the updated item though.

My question: Is it possible to update and return the modified item in a single line?

What I tried so far:

```
await this.taskRepository.updateById(id, { state, dueDate });
return this.taskRepository.findOne({ id });
```

What I'm looking for:

```
return this.taskRepository.updateById(id, { state, dueDate }); // returns updated task
```

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I just found out that I can do this with the `.save` method:

```
return this.taskRepository.save({
    id: task.id,
    state,
    dueDate
});
```

According to [the docs](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api) (section `save`), partial updates are supported as well:

> Also supports partial updating since all undefined properties are skipped.

Comment: What is "task"? That wasn't mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Dugi This is just an entity. And yes it‘s mentioned in the question. Even the Repo is called like that. :)

Comment: I'm talking about the `..task` variable spreading. That just came out of nowhere and isn't in the original question; there you use `id`.

Comment: Be aware that `.save` will also create a new Entity when it doesn't exist. This  might not always be desired. So `.update` would be a smarter choice and then still do a `.findOne(id: task.id)` to return the entire object.

Comment: I am maybe incorrect, but from my testing, when you use `.save` to update entity, this method is NOT returning entity back when you use `{...oldEntity, ...updates}`, but only plain object which can be problem for `class-serializer` for example.

Comment: @Baterka What do you mean by plain object? It returns the entity as usual with typeorm.

Comment: this answer is incorrect as #save will only return you the properties that you provided, and not the full entity.

Comment: What version do you use @Calvintwr? It's possible that this changed with >= 0.3.x

Comment: @sandrooco I stand corrected. I did further testing and it does return return the full entity. I apologise, and have upvoted the answer Additionally, I have proposed some improvements to be comprehensive. Because the desire is indeed to update and return, and #save does have the pitfall of creating new entities whether it is intended or not.

Answer (score 42):

To expand on sandrooco's answer, this is what I do:

```
const property = await this.propertyRepository.findOne({
  where: { id }
});

return this.propertyRepository.save({
  ...property, // existing fields
  ...updatePropertyDto // updated fields
});
```

Comment: This still makes 2 calls to the Db. Is there a way to make it make just one call. For example, in Postgres, you can run

```
UPDATE ..
SET ..
RETURNING *
```

and it would update the data and return the updated rows

Comment: @Chidiebere I'm having the same issue. Did you find a way to save without TypeOrm doing duplicate select statements?

Comment: I didn't find a way around this( I just made two calls there) but one thing I have resolved to do is to write raw queries anywhere I have these kinds of optimization issues that a raw query can give me.

Comment: This is kind of useless, you don't even need the existing fields (except the `id` of course).

Answer (score 33):

#### `response.raw[0]` in order to get the type back.

---

Although I want `await Table.update({}, {})` to return `Table` it doesn't. Instead do:

```
const post = (await Post.update({id}, {...input})).raw[0];
return post; // returns post of type Post
```

Others above has mentioned the usage of `Repository` and `Table.save()` Which doesn't really return the original `type` anywhere, so that approach is out of the picture for me.

An example of `Table.update({}, {})`:

```
@Mutation(() => PostResponse, { nullable: true })
async updatePost(
  @Arg("id", () => Int) id: number,
  @Arg("input") input: PostInput,
): Promise<PostResponse | null> {
  const post = (await Post.update({id}, {...input})).raw[0];
  return { post };
}
```

An example of `QueryBuilder`:

```
@Mutation(() => PostResponse, { nullable: true })
@UseMiddleware(isAuthorized)
async updatePost(
  @Arg("id", () => Int) id: number,
  @Arg("input") input: PostInput,
  @Ctx() { req }: Context
): Promise<PostResponse | null> {
  const post = await (Post.createQueryBuilder()
    .update(Post)
    .set({ ...input })
    .where('id = :id and "creatorId" = :creatorId', {
      id,
      creatorId: userId,
    })
    .returning("*")
    .execute())
    .raw[0];

  return { post };
}
```

---

*Note: I'm using TypeORM and Type-GraphQL here.*

*`.returning("*")` does not work on MySQL, see comments below.*

Comment: This seems a far more better option that to use find/save or update/find. Interesting that this isn't upvoted

Comment: @Joey587 I updated the answer to include a different approach using the `Table.update({}, {})` method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, @Joel

This question should state its specific to Microsoft SQL Server and/or PostgreSQL, though, as this is not supported for MySQL: `.returning("*")`

That renders the answer invalid for those using MySQL.

Comment: @RafaelLeite Good catch, haven't verified this myself, but I can add a note regarding it.

Comment: Can someone please tag this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to perform the update and then do a find based on the condition you specified

Comment: This makes 2 queries to the database and is not atomic.

Comment: @Xetera That's very true. If you are on PostgreSQL you could just write a raw query that performs the update and returns it ([see this](https://gist.github.com/prestonp/0b5cd2416b4b3853db3f)) 

eg.

```
UPDATE <table-name>
  SET c=value

RETURNING *

```

If you are not using Postgres then you might as well just perform an update and a find in a transaction.

What do you think

Comment: This is precisely what I didn't want to do...

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this to validate if exists or not for `.save` method,

```
async findOne(id: string): Promise<Manufacturer> {
    const found = await this.repository.findOneBy({ id });

    if (!found) {
        throw new NotFoundException(`Could not find ${this.Entity.name} with id: ${id}`);
    }

    return found;
}

async update(id: string, updateEmployeeDto: UpdateManufacturerDto): Promise<Manufacturer> {
    await this.findOne(id);

    return this.repository.save({ id, ...updateEmployeeDto });
}
```

Comment: 1. Question was "Is it possible to update and return the modified item in a single line?" --> SINGLE line
2. there's findOneOrFail for that

Comment: Ow, tnx for the clarification didn't know that. Me -> new to TypeORM

Comment: .raw[0] is an empty array and doesn't work .