# Typeorm querybuilder update get updated result

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typeorm

I'm running a query-builder that updates multiple users based on last logged in date, meaning I don't know which users are getting updated. Here is my code, which does not provide information about which users it updated.

```
await getConnection()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update(User)
  .set({
    isDeactivated: true
  })
  .where('lastConnected < :someTimeAgo', { someTimeAgo })
  .andWhere('isDeactivated = :isDeactivated', { isDeactivated: false })
  .execute()
  .then(result => {
    // Result: UpdateResult { generatedMaps: [], raw: undefined }
  })
```

How can I access the updated data? Database is SQL Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792808/typeorm-update-item-and-return-it

Comment: Are you missing "not" in "which does provide information about which users it updated" (I see you originally wrote "which does provide any informations about which users it updated", "not" seems to be missing).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you cannot find which rows were updated by an `UPDATE` statement in SQL, hence tyeorm cannot tell you.

Here are several solutions if you REALLY need to know which rows were updated.

Before go ahead, ask WHY do you need to know? Do you REALLY need to know?

If, after careful consideration, you find you need to know which rows were updated, there are several solutions:

1. In your code, find the users to be deleted, then delete them one at a time, logging info on each one as you go.
2. Create a table in the database containing the user id's to be deactivated. Populate this table first: `INSERT INTO deactivatedusers (userid) SELECT userid FROM users WHERE ...` then run `UPDATE users SET isDeactivated = 1 WHERE userid IN SELECT userid FROM  deactivatedusers` then to find which users were deactivated: `SELECT userid FROM  deactivatedusers` and finally clear deactivatedusers ready for next time, either with `DELETE FROM deactivatedusers` or `TRUNCATE TABLE deactivatedusers`
3. Since you are using MS SQL Server, this provides [OUTPUT INTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms177564(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#e-using-output-into-with-from_table_name-in-an-update-statement) specifically to do what you are asking (non standard SQL, so only works with this DBMS). If you decide to use this approach, you should write a stored procedure to do the update and return the updated data back to caller, then call this stored proc from typeorm.

Comment: It makes sense that TypeORM cannot tell me due to SQL not giving the data. I ended up with a solution close to your solution 1. First I find the users to deactivate and add them to an array, then do a batch-update where I set isDeactivated on all of them, before writing a log with all newly deactivated users. 
Thanks for your response