# TypeORM: Updating columns data

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I have a situation where i'm trying to update columns in typeorm. I have a `1-to-1` relationship between my `User` entity and `Profile` entity. How can  I update the profile of the user based on the following conditions:

1. I'm using type-graphql to get data from the client.
2. I only want to update the fields that the client provide data for.

Here is what I've tried so far in my `UpdateUser` Resolver

```
@Resolver()
export class UpdateAccountResolver {
  @Mutation(() => UpdateProfileObjectType)
  async updateProfile(
    @Ctx() {}: UserContext,
    @Arg("input", () => UpdateInput)
    {
      avatar,
      bio,
      email,
      gender,
      verified,
      username,
      status,
      phoneNumber,
      userId,
    }: UpdateInput
  ): Promise<UpdateProfileObjectType> {
    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: { id: userId },
      relations: ["profile", "posts"],
    });
    if (!user) {
      return {
        error: {
          field: "user",
          message: "could not find the user with a given id.",
        },
      };
    }
    let profileObject = {} as any;
    try {
      if (avatar) {
        const { secure_url } = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(avatar, {
          public_id: `${user.id}:${uuid_v4()}`,
          upload_preset: "likeme",
          folder: "avatars",
        });
        console.log("secured url", secure_url);
        profileObject["avatar"] = secure_url;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (bio) profileObject["bio"] = bio;
    if (email) profileObject["email"] = email;
    if (gender) profileObject["gender"] = gender;
    if (verified) profileObject["verified"] = verified;
    if (username) profileObject["username"] = username;
    if (status) profileObject["status"] = status;
    if (phoneNumber) profileObject["phoneNumber"] = phoneNumber;

    // const profile = new Profile();
    
    console.log(profile);
     const profile = await getConnection()
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(Profile)
      .set({
        ...profileObject,
      })
      .where("id = :id", { id: user.profile.id })
      .select("*")
      .where("id = :id", { id: user.profile.id })
      .getOne();

    if (profile) {
      user.profile = profile;
      console.log("the profile itself....", profile);
      await user.save();
    }

    console.log("user is here....", user);

    return {
      user,
    };
  }
}
```

This is not working, I've tried the example that they have in their docs, but it seems to I've to write a lot of if statements, because I only want to update the field `email` if the client provide the email, otherwise I just ignore that column. Let's hope this makes sense, if you need more code let' me know so that i will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: `if (email) return await User.update({id}, {email}).then(resp => resp.raw[0])`

Comment: maybe this answer will help u get a better understanding of what I mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792808/typeorm-update-item-and-return-it/64116762#64116762 I'm honestly not quite sure what u are looking for.