# TypeORM: return updated object with single call to database? (async/await)

Tags: async-await, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

TypeORM's `entity.update()` method does not return the updated object but a simple success/failure notification. The updated object can then be returned by doing `entity.findOne()` after the update, but that means two back and forth calls to the database instead of just one.

I've seen some people using `entity.save()` to do partial updates, but this creates new entities if the object does not exist, which is not desired. I could also use `.then()`, but I don't want to mix thens with my `async/await` code.

Is there any way of returning the updated entity in TypeORM with a single call to the database?

Edit:
My question originates from the answers and comments in this thread: [TypeORM: update item and return it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792808/typeorm-update-item-and-return-it)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways such as using queryBuilder.

You can see this, the answers to this question provide a lot of possible examples => [TypeORM: update item and return it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792808/typeorm-update-item-and-return-it)

Comment: The comments to the responses in that thread is what triggered my question =) The 3 main responses either a) save a new entity if the object to update does not exist, b) make two calls to the database, or c) .then() is used instead of async/await. I was wondering if there was a solution that can be used with async/await and doesn't have the problems a) and b).