# return updated entity with entityRepository

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Is there any way to update an entity and return the result of the operation USING entity repository and NOT query Builder?

```
const result = await this.shipmentRepository.createQueryBuilder('sh')
            .update()
            .set({ ...infoToUpdate })
            .where('shipment_number = :shipmentNumber', { shipmentNumber })
            .returning("*")
            .execute()

        return result.raw[0]
```

I'm using this ^, this works properly but I want to know if I can do it using this syntaxis

```
const result = await this.shipmentRepository.update({ shipment_number: shipmentNumber }, infoToUpdate)
```

TypeORM documentation doesnt say anything about it
Can you help me? Thank u a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeORM: update item and return it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47792808/typeorm-update-item-and-return-it)

Comment: thank for the reply but it does not work actually. Entity repository just dont give anything back. If i use queryBuilder yes, i can use the property that the link's response says.
Thank u